# Вывод ошибки php

Tags: json, php

Здравствуйте.

Есть у меня такая функция:

```
function senden( startfrom ){

    $.post("http://site.ru/site.php?user_hash={$site}", { startfrom: startfrom, area: 'site_go' },
        function(data){

            if (data) {

                if (data.status == "ok") {

                    $('#sitecount').html(data.rebuildcount);
                    $('#site_ok').val(data.rebuildcount);

                    var proc = Math.round( (100 * data.rebuildcount) / total );

                    if ( proc > 100 ) proc = 100;

                    $('#progressbar').width( proc + '%');

                     if (data.rebuildcount >= total) 
                     {
                          $('#progress').html('Успешно завершено');
                     }
                     else 
                     { 
                          setTimeout("senden(" + data.rebuildcount + ")", 2000 );
                     }

                }

            }
        }, "json");

    return false;
}
```

Когда у меня ошибка в php, не выводит мне ошибку на экран. Когда все хорошо, то все работает.

Как вывести, к примеру, результат ошибки на экран в

`<div id="site_error"></div>` ?

Ошибки выводятся в php у меня, как обычно, в php `die('Вы разлогинелись');.`

Comment: Уже весь интернет перелопатил и так ответа не нашел...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда появляются какие-то ошибки в php, то нарушается формат JSON, который ты запрашиваешь последним агрументом при вызове `$.post`.

Выход есть: нужно запрашивать не `json`, а `text`, после чего самому пытаться разобрать:

```
try {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
}
catch (e) {
    alert(data);
}
```

Если разобрать JSON не удастся — значит вывод некорректен, вероятно, что в выводе присутствует сообщение об ошибке PHP.

#### UPD

В твоем случае весь код будет выглядеть так:

```
function senden( startfrom ) {
    $.post("http://site.ru/site.php?user_hash={$site}", { startfrom: startfrom, area: 'site_go' },
        function(data) {
            try {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
            }
            catch (e) {
                $('#site_error').html(data);
                data = false;
            }
            
            if (data && data.status == "ok") {
                $('#sitecount').html(data.rebuildcount);
                $('#site_ok').val(data.rebuildcount);

                var proc = Math.round( (100 * data.rebuildcount) / total );

                if ( proc > 100 ) proc = 100;

                $('#progressbar').width( proc + '%');

                if (data.rebuildcount >= total) {
                    $('#progress').html('Успешно завершено');
                }
                else { 
                    setTimeout("senden(" + data.rebuildcount + ")", 2000 );
                }
            }
        });

    return false;
}
```

В случае возникновения ошибки, она будет отображена в `#site_error`.

А вообще, гораздо удобнее использовать PhpConsole — расширение для Chrome и маленькая библиотека на PHP, которые дадут возможность видеть ошибки в DevTools Chrom-а. Ошибки, возникающие в процессе выполнения AJAX к своему хосту тоже будут перехвачены.

Comment: А как это применить в моей функции?